# Prove $T_n(x)$ of Chebyshev Polynomial given the recurrence relation

Tags: numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Using the recursion formula for Chebyshev polynomials, show that $T_n(x)$ can be written as 
$$T_n(x)=2^{n-1}(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)$$ 
where $x_i$ are the $n$ roots of $T_n$

The recurrence relation: $T_0(x)=1$,$T_1(x)=x$, and $T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$

I have an intuition that I need to use induction,but what is my inductive hypothesis?

Here is my work:

Assume $T_n(x)=2^{n-1}(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)$

Prove $T_{n+1}(x)=2^{n}(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)(x-x_{n+1})$

Use the definition of Chebyshev polynomial, $T_n(x) = cos(n\theta),x =cos(\theta)$

$T_0(x)=1$ and $T_1(x)=x$

And then use the recursion formula $T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$, I get

$T_{n+1}(x) = 2x[2^{n-1}(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)]-[2^{n-2}(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_{n-1})]$

Then

$T_{n+1}(x) = 2x(2^{-1})(x-x_n)[2^n(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_{n-1})]-2^{-2}[2^n(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_{n-1})]$

Rearrange I get

$T_{n+1}(x) = [2x(2^{-1})(x-x_n)-2^{-2}][2^n(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_{n-1})]$

What should I do next(assume what I did above is correct) so that I can get $T_{n+1}(x)=2^{n}(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)(x-x_{n+1})$ ??

Comment: Since the recurrence relation uses the previous *two* polynomials, in order to establish the formula for $T_{n+1}(x)$, you have to assume that the analogous formula holds for both $T_n(x)$ and $T_{n-1}(x)$.  Notice that you need *two* base cases.

Comment: And your base cases are showing this holds for $T_1,T_2$.

Comment: I have made some progress, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inductive hypothesis is: $T_n=2^{n-1}x^n+f_n(x)$ where $\deg f\le n-1$.

**Addendum:** From  $T_n=2^{n-1}x^n+f_n(x)$ we have  $T_{n+1}=2^nx^{n+1} +2xf_n(x)-2^{n-2}x^{n-1}-f_{n-1}(x)$ and evidently $\deg f_{n+1}(x)\le n$ where $f_{n+1}(x)=2xf_n(x)-2^{n-2}x^{n-1}-f_{n-1}(x)$.

Further if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are the roots of $T_n$, we get  $T_n=2^{n-1}(x-x_1)\ldots(x-x_n)$.

Comment: I have made some progresses but still could not prove the formula for $T_n(x)$, can you take a look and give me more hints?

Comment: I added the answer.

Comment: Does my method not working? (ie. is it possible to express $T_{n+1}(x)$ explicitly as $2^{n}(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)(x-x_{n+1})$ through algebraic steps?

Comment: You suppose that the roots $x_i$ of $T_n$ are also roots of $T_{n+1}$.